# Updating the guild.members in discord.py Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a Python Bot which tracks the time a user has spent in voice state on a server to create a ranking system. Unfortunaley i dont know how to update the guild.members list and thus the member.voice value.
I tried doing a while loop but the list didnt seem to update.
Help would be greately appreciated.

```
# bot.py
import os
import asyncio
import discord
import random
import datetime
from discord.utils import get
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import tasks

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.name == GUILD, client.guilds)

        for m in guild.members:
            print(m.voice)
            time.sleep(2)




client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Can you show some code of what you did?

Comment: Always show what you have tried, so that others have a general idea of what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for not adding code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `on_voice_state_update()` event to keep track of every single member that connects / disconnect from a voice channel. Make sure to use the `discord.ext.commands` client object.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if not before.channel and after.channel:
        await start_tracking(member) #your method that tracks the time
                                     #Remember that it has to be a coroutine
    if before.channel and not after.channel:
        await stop_tracking(member)
```

edit: please do not use `time.sleep()` in async scripts. use `asyncio` for stuff like sleeping and for loops